# How to set interval in animated gradient text?

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a interval while my animated gradient text is running but I don't know how to do it with CSS only.
I have 3 different colors and I'd like to initiate it in black, turn to colored and back to black again, like a loop.

**HTML**

```
<h2 className="gradient-text">
 Text Exemple
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
.gradient-text {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #000, #2FEBDC, #EB413B, #FFA300, #E422EB);
    background-size:400%;
    animation: text-gradient 8s linear infinite;
    padding:5px 0;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
      text-fill-color: transparent;
   }
   
   @keyframes text-gradient {
    0% {
     background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
     background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
     background-position: 50% 100%;
    }
   }
```

Is it possible using only CSS instead javascript?

Comment: What do you mean set an interval?

Comment: It's just like a "interval" (in black color) to turn the text in another colored. Exemple: initiate the text in black, then turn colored and then back to black again (like a interval). @teefars

Comment: An interval is "a pause or break in activity", I don't see how to put an interval visually. Your code seems to be transitioning properly, isn't it the result you want?

Comment: Not that way! Imagine that I have blue, red and green... I'd like to initiate my text in black, then turn in blue and black again, turn to red and black again and finally turn green and black again... thanks for help already @teefars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `animation-direction` is by default set to `normal`. In order to get back to black in reverse order (i.e, black -> coloured -> black), set it to `alternate`. This will cycle between playing the animation forwards and backwards.
- In order to set a play interval, (i.e, wait at black for a particular amount of time before resuming the animation), you can set two keyframes with no changes between the two. This will make your animation stay put for a set duration before resuming. You will have to increase the `animation-duration` if you want to retain the speed at which your animation plays.
- Your CSS may look something like so:

```
.gradient-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #000, #2FEBDC, #EB413B, #FFA300, #E422EB);
    animation: text-gradient 10s linear alternate infinite;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-clip: text;
    background-size: 400%;
}

@keyframes text-gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    33% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    66% {
        background-position: 50% 100%;
    } /* In my example here, this keyframe at 66% is not needed as the animation is progressing linearly from 33% to 100% anyways... it can be omitted */

    100% {
        background-position: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to start the animation from left to right?

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean you want to move your gradient background image from left to right? If so, just edit the keyframes and move it in whichever direction you desire.